# Batch Script to create folder based on name, add to existing code

Tags: batch-file, directory

The code below works fine, here is a list of it's functions:

1. It moves files based on the fist 4 characters to a pre-created folder with the same first 4 characters
2. If the folder does not exist, it will not move the file, as there is no folder with the same fist 4 chars.

   ```
   @echo on
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   cls

   pushd R:\Contracts\Sites

   for /f "tokens=*" %%1 in ('dir /a-d /b *') do (
       set filename=%%1&set dirname=!filename:~0,4!

       for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /ad /b') do (
            set dirid=%%A & set dirid=!dirid:~0,4!

            if "!dirid!" equ "!dirname!" move %%1 %%A
       )        
   )
   ```

I would like to add one extra function to this code please. Pleas have a look at the example below.

I have 5 files

- X32A-test.docx or X32A-test.pptx (there will only be one docx or pptx, "NEVER two with the same name")
- X32A-test.pdf
- X32A-test.avi
- X32A-test-eng.sub
- X32A-test-small.jpg

I would like the code to CREATE a folder if it does not exist, based on the file name if it has the extension docx or pptx.

So with the above example it would create a folder named: "X32A-test". Then all the other files with "X32A" in the front of the name will be moved to that newly created folder "X32A-test".

I hope it is clear enough. If not please ask me for more information.

Thank you

Comment: @Christian.K - Thank you. I could not get it to make it all code.

Comment: No worries. Just mark all text you want as code and use the "{}" button in the editor (or indent every code-line with 4 spaces or more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the entire process (including the part already implemented) like this:

1. All the files that are not yet in their "home" directories are moved there.
2. For all `.docx` and `.pptx` files left, create directories based on the files' names.
3. Obviously, the step #2 creates new "homes" and those will still be "uninhabited" this far. So all that is left to do now is to repeat the step #1.

So I would probably reorganised your process and, with the additional requirement, it could be implemented this way:

```
…

PUSHD your_root_directory

FOR /D %%D IN (*) DO (
  CALL :movefiles "%%D"
)

FOR %%F in (*.docx *.pptx) DO (
  MKDIR "%%~dpnF"
  CALL :movefiles "%%~dpnF"
)

…

GOTO :EOF

:movefiles
SET "dirname=%~n1"
SET "mask=%dirname:~0,4%*"
MOVE "%~dp1%mask%" %1
```

Note: The steps #2 and #3 could be either implemented as separate loops or combined in one. The above script uses the latter approach.

Answer (score 2):

It is much simpler and more efficient to use the simple FOR instead of FOR /F in your case.

And rather than looping through every file and moving them individually, it is easier and more efficient to use wildcards.

The first loop finds the .pptx and .docx files and creates folders as needed

The second loop finds all the directories and moves all files that start with the directory name into the directory.

```
@echo on
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
cls

pushd R:\Contracts\Sites

for %%F in (*.docx *.pptx) do (
  set "folder=%%F"
  2>nul md !folder:~0,4!
)
for /d %%F in (*) do move %%F* %%F
popd
```

If needed, you can protect yourself against directory names shorter than length 4.

```
@echo on
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
cls

pushd R:\Contracts\Sites

for %%F in (*.docx *.pptx) do (
  set "folder=%%F"
  set folder=!folder:~0,4!
  if !folder:~0,3! neq !folder! 2>nul md !folder!
)
for /d %%F in (????) do (
  set "folder=%%F"
  if "!folder:~0,3!" neq "%%F" move %%F* %%F
)
popd
```

Note that this solution may fail if a file name contains `!`. If that arises then you need to toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop(s).

Comment: It creates a folder however it should use the entire name. E.g. 2382-test-music-luck.docx, it should make a folder 2382-test-music-luck.dock      Thank you

Comment: @Arthor: Sorry, but *‘So with the above example it would create a folder named: "X32A-test".’* – was *your* words, man. Now you say that it should include extension. Is there anything else you failed to mention correctly in your question?

Comment: Sorry... One sec..... Only this...2382-test-music-luck   It does not need the extension.. Only the entire folder name.. Sorry @Andriy M

Comment: @dbenham: Most likely using the `~n` specifier should be enough.

Comment: @Andriy M - Hello Andriy, could you give me an idea where I need to put the code. I have been playing around with it, but not getting the results I want. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative offsets in the `!var:~offset,len!` evaluation as follows:

```
set fspec=X32A-test.docx
echo !fspec:~-10!
echo !fspec:~0,-10!
```

That second line above gives you `-test.docx` and you can simply check that against your two desired possibilities with an `if` statement (or two).

Then you can use the third line to get the rest of the name for creating a directory.

The following example script shows how this could be done:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set fspec=X32A-test.docx
set bit1=!fspec:~-10!
set bit2=!fspec:~0,-10!
if .!bit1!.==.-test.docx. echo mkdir !bit2!
if .!bit1!.==.-test.pptx. echo mkdir !bit2!
endlocal
```

I'm echoing the `mkdir` command rather than executing it so you need to take out the `echo`. You'll also need to integrate the `set` and `if` statements into your loop but, based on what you have so far, you should have little trouble with that.

---

If, as you seem to indicate in a comment, the first four characters are the key and the last five decide on whether to make the directory, as in:

```
x32s-test.docx
a21w-production.pptx
xxxx-whatever_the_blazes_you_want.some_other_rubbish.docx
```

Then you're really only interested in the first four and last five:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set fspec=a12b-whatever_the_blazes_you_want.some_other_rubbish.docx
set bit1=!fspec:~-5!
set bit2=!fspec:~0,4!
if .!bit1!.==..docx. echo mkdir !bit2!
if .!bit1!.==..pptx. echo mkdir !bit2!
endlocal
```

This checks the correct extensions and outputs:

```
mkdir a12b
```

as expected.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick response. I understand the concept however I think there is an issue. X32A-test.docx is not be the only file name. There will be 100s of files following the same example above. e.g. X32A-test.docx, XS1A-test.docx, 64SA-test.docx. I thought it would have to identify the docx or pptx first, then get the files name with out the extension, then check to see if the folder name exists, if it does not create it, if it does, move on. Thank you

Comment: @Arthor, that's what it will do. The two `if` statements will detect the end of the file name (using `bit1`, the last ten characters, in this case) and only act if they match a certain pattern. If actioned, the `mkdir` will use all but the last ten characters `bit2` to make the directory. It doesn't really matter whether the directory exists. If not, `mkdir` will create it. If so, it will simply error and carry on.

Comment: GREAT.... Right, let me give it a try... Please note I am not a coder BUT I am willing to learn... So here goes... Thank you

Comment: Aaaa OK I have noticed my mistake, Imagine these files name: X32A-test.docx, X31B-the-living-garden.docx, 1S2A-the-cream-of-all.docx. Sorry I do not mean to sound stupid. The 4 first chars is the primary key and the rest after is the file name. Will this make files even thought the file name is not test. I am just making sure...

Comment: No problems, @Arthor, I've updated the answer so that it only checks the extension and only uses the first four characters as the directory name. If that's not quite what you want, it should be relatively easy to adapt it.

Comment: Almost. You put "mkdir a12b". but if the folder to be created is the a12b and the files name. E.g. a23b-good-games.docx  It should be mkdir "a23b-good-games". The folder name needs to be the entire file name with out the DOCX.